# How to apply divergence theorem to transform 2D integral to 1D integral?

Tags: vector-analysis, contour-integration, divergence-operator

I am trying to understand Medina and Jones's paper, "Leading-edge vortex burst on a low-aspect-ratio rotating flat plate"(2016).

They derived an equation in the appendix of this paper. They said divergence theorem was used in plane to get the relationship below.

$$\int_A\nabla_{2D} \cdot(\vec u_{2D}\omega _z)dA=\int_S \vec n_{2D}\cdot \vec u_{2D}\omega_{z}dS$$
$$\text{where} \quad \nabla_{2D}=(\partial/\partial x , \partial/\partial y)\quad \text{and} \quad \vec u_{2D}=(u,v)$$ 
$$A\text{ is an area pointing in the $z$ direction, bounded by perimeter $S$}$$

As far as I know divergence theorem transforms 3D to 2D or vice versa. Is there a way to apply divergence theorem to transform 2D to 1D?

Comment: You can see: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/greens-theorem-and-stokes-theorem/2d-divergence-theorem-ddp/v/2-d-divergence-theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general version of the "[divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)":

$$
\int_U \nabla\cdot F\ dV=\int_{\partial U}F\cdot\nu \ dS
$$
where $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set with "nice" boundary and $F$ is a smooth function. When $n=2$, this is related to [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Relationship_to_the_divergence_theorem).